# InetAddress.getByName on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I do a:

```
java.net.InetAddress serverAddr;
try {
    serverAddr = java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Server.SERVERNAME);
}
catch (java.net.UnknownHostException exception) {
    //System.err.println ("wrong server name !!!");
    HelloWorldActivity.tv.setText("wrong server name !!!");
    return;
}
```

in my android application, but it's never resoling the hostname, it always throws an exception, no matter what name I use.

But using the internet on the same emulator works, and I've added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

to AndoidManifest.xml

and here's the server class for those who assume I have none

```
public class Server
{
    public static String SERVERNAME = "monster.idsoftware.com";
    public static String SERVERIP = "209.85.129.99";
    public static int SERVERPORT = 27950;
    public static int PROTOCOL = 68;
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you have a Server.java class? I know that UnknwnHostException gets thrown when the address lookup fails.

Comment: this code would be querying quake servers, whats your desired output?

Comment: query monster.idsoftware.com on UDP by resolving the hostname, connecting to that IP via UDP on port 27950, sending "ÿÿÿÿgetservers 68 'all'" where 68 is the protocol version.
Receiving a hostlist UTF-7 encoded, decoding it to a list of ip's+ports, displaying that list. But I'm stuck at issue 1.

Comment: my best advice is try to load that onto an external android device and test from there, I don't know if you can work with UDP on the emulator

Comment: it might be an issue with the proxy, or nat.

Comment: I have the same issue, `InetAddress.getAllByName` doesn't work, but I can get the page source with `BufferedReader` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer. For whatever reason, you have to use:

```
java.net.InetAddress[] x = java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Server.SERVERNAME);
HelloWorldActivity.tv.setText("Address: "+x[0].getHostAddress());
```

Answer (score 8):

I was having the similar issue and I found out that in some versions of android (from honeycombs) it's not allowed by default to perform network operation from main thread. So you can resolve it in 2 ways. Perform operation in different thread or allow to make network operation in main thread. To do that use something like this:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: while this is true it is a very bad practice to make connections on the UI thread because it blocks the thread.

Comment: Although this solution would work, it's not recommended and is a bad practice. Use AsyncTasks for performing network operations in different thread.

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that you have to do so. `java.net.InetAddress.getByName` works for me, out of the box.

There are some (on-going) issues related to DNS resolution in the Android emulator, so that might be it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it was a typo, but you said you have:

```
<use-permission id="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But it have to be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I tried getByName and it works fine.

May be you fixed your permissions and switched from getByName to getAllByName at the same time? Just curious, if you can confirm that getByName still does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, try to resolve dns-name of local PC from the default browser (Google Chrome). If he can't - trouble in the router settings or abilities...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).