# android serverSocket initialisation causing permission denied exception in service(remote)

Tags: java, android, serversocket

I am trying to create a socket with a hardcoded IP address and socket in a remote process:

```
server = new ServerSocket(80);
```

and I am getting a permission denied exception even though I have added the INTERNET permission in the manifest file.

What could be possibly wrong in this?

Comment: Did you ever get a good solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this question may help:

- [InetAddress.getByName on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096874/inetaddress-getbyname-on-android)