# android java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host

Tags: android, exception, connection

So, I'm trying to send POST requests to an IP adress, but I've found a problem way before that. 
To check if there's a working connection to the internet I have the following method called when creating the Activity:

```
public void checkInternectConnection() {
        AsyncTask.execute(() -> {

            try {
                InetAddress inAddress = InetAddress.getByName("https://google.com");
                if (inAddress.equals("")) {
                    networkAvilable = true;
                } else {
                    networkAvilable = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                networkAvilable = false;
            }
        });
}
```

When this code is executed, it always catches the exception `java.net.UnkonwnHostException: Unable to resolve host "https://google.com": No address associated with hostname.`

I've serched the error and all I can find is that the app doasn't have Internet permissions, but I have in the android manifest that permission already ( `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`)

I've also tried with `http://google.com` instead of `https`, but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097594/5110595)

Comment: `InetAddress.getByName()` takes a hostname, and the protocol (http://) is not part of the hostname. Check Muhammad's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check internet connection like this:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

In manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This method actually checks if device is connected to internet(There is a possibility it's connected to a network but not to internet).

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); 
        //You can replace it with your name
            return !ipAddr.equals("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
    }
}
```