# Throwing IOException in Interceptor is causing the crash with Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, interceptor, ioexception

I am trying to handle the exceptions due to the server and client network connections. 
I have made an Interceptor class for handling those errors globally as the square docs.
Every time I tried to execute the network calls without a network connection, this error kicked in and causing my app to crash.

Edited : If the connection is too slow enough to trigger SocketTimeOutExeception , it also caused the app to crash. I have tried to cover it with a way in which the network calls will only be executed if there is an active network connection. But like I said before, the connection is too slow , the error kicked in the same with  SocketTimeOutExeception. The app works well with a good, active network connection

```
W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "0725394a.ngrok.io": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:157)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.kt:49)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.kt:164)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.kt:129)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.kt:71)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:197)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:107)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:75)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:245)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:74)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at com.network.di.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.kt:63)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at com.network.exception.NetworkExceptionInterceptor.intercept(NetworkExceptionInterceptor.kt:11)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at com.readystatesoftware.chuck.ChuckInterceptor.intercept(ChuckInterceptor.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:219)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:188)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:97)
W/System.err:     at com.network.datasource.CourseDetailsDataSourcecImpl.getChaptersByPagination(CourseDetailsDataSourcecImpl.kt:39)
        at com.data.repository.CourseDetailsRepositoryImpl.getChapterList(CourseDetailsRepositoryImpl.kt:19)
        at com.domain.interactors.coursedetails.GetCourseChaptersByPagination$provideObservable$1.call(GetCourseChaptersByPagination.kt:26)
        at com.domain.interactors.coursedetails.GetCourseChaptersByPagination$provideObservable$1.call(GetCourseChaptersByPagination.kt:11)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromCallable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromCallable.java:43)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12246)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This is the error I've been getting.

This are my interceptor classes

```
class AuthenticationInterceptor() : Interceptor {
    private var bearerToken : String? = ""
    private var token : String? = ""
    private var customToken : String? = null
    private var customTag : String? = null
    private var onlyUseCustomHeader : Boolean = false

    private var customName : String? = null


    fun setCustom(customName : String? , customTag : String? , customToken : String?) {
        this.customToken = customToken
        this.customTag = customTag
        this.customName = customName
    }


    fun setOnlyUseCustomHeader(onlyUseCustomHeader : Boolean) {
        this.onlyUseCustomHeader = onlyUseCustomHeader
    }


    constructor(
        bearerToken : String?,
        token : String?
    ) : this() {
        this.bearerToken = bearerToken
        this.token = token
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain : Interceptor.Chain) : Response {
        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        if (!onlyUseCustomHeader) {
            if (customName != null && customToken != null) {
                if (customTag == null)
                    builder.addHeader("$customName" , "$customToken")
                else
                    builder.addHeader("$customName" , "$customTag $customToken")
            }

            if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken != "")
                builder.addHeader("Authorization" , "Bearer $bearerToken")
            if (token != null && token != "")
                builder.addHeader("token" , "$token")
        } else {
            if (customName != null && customToken != null) {
                if (customTag == null)
                    builder.addHeader("$customName" , "$customToken")
                else
                    builder.addHeader("$customName" , "$customTag $customToken")
            }
        }
        builder.addHeader("Accept" , "application/json")

        val request = builder.build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

}
```

```
class NetworkExceptionInterceptor : Interceptor {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        when (response.isSuccessful) {
            true  -> return response
            false -> {
                throw NetworkException(response.body , response.code)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my custom error class.

```
data class NetworkException constructor(
    var errorBody: ResponseBody? = null,
    var errorCode: Int
) : IOException()
```

These are the methods for providing OkhttpClient and Retrofit.Builder() where I added the Network Interceptor and the Authenticating interceptor.

```
        @Provides
        fun providesOkHttpClientBuilder(context : Context) : OkHttpClient.Builder {

            return OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {

                val loggerInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                    level = when (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        true  -> HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS
                        false -> HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
                    }
                }

                addInterceptor(loggerInterceptor)
                      .addInterceptor(ChuckInterceptor(context))
                    .addInterceptor(NetworkExceptionInterceptor())
                    .readTimeout(8 , TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(8 , TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(8 , TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .cache(null)
            }
        }

   @JvmStatic
        @NonNull
        @Named("authenticatedBuilder")
        @Provides
        fun getAuthenticatedBuilder(@Named("bearer_token") bearerToken : String? , @Named("token") token : String? , httpClientBuilder : OkHttpClient.Builder ,@Named("primary") retrofitBuilder : Retrofit.Builder) : Retrofit.Builder {
            showLogD("NETWORK_MODULE" , "BearerToken before interception : $bearerToken")
            showLogD("NETWORK_MODULE" , "TOKEN before interception : $token")
            val interceptor : Interceptor =
                AuthenticationInterceptor(bearerToken , token)
            if (!httpClientBuilder.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
                httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptor)
            }
            return retrofitBuilder.client(httpClientBuilder.build())

        }
```

Edited 2 : This is the CourseDetailsDataSourceImpl.kt

```
class CourseDetailsDataSourcecImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val courseDetailsService : CourseDetailsService ,
    private val courseDetailsMapper : CourseDetailsMapper ,
    private val chapterListMapper : CourseChapterListMapper ,
    private val lessonSnapShotMapper : LessonSnapShotMapper ,
    private val vdoPlayerOTPMapper : VdoPlayerOTPMapper
) : CourseDetailsDataSource {

    @Inject
    lateinit var vdoPlayerService : VdoPlayerService

    override fun getCourseDetails(courseID : String) : CourseDetailsVO {
        return courseDetailsMapper.map(courseDetailsService.getCourseDetails(courseID).execute().body()!!)
    }

    override fun getCourseVideoDetails(lessonID : String) : LessonSnapShotVO {
        return lessonSnapShotMapper.map(courseDetailsService.getLessonDetails(lessonID).execute().body()!!)
    }

    override fun getChaptersByPagination(courseID : String , pageNumber : Int) : CourseChapterListVO{
        //todo implement this with pagination
        return chapterListMapper.map(courseDetailsService.getCourseChapters(courseID).execute().body()!!)
    }

    override fun getVdoPlayerOtp(videoID : String) : VdoPlayerOTPResponseVO {
        return vdoPlayerOTPMapper.map(vdoPlayerService.getOtp( videoID , VDOOTPRequestBody()).execute().body()!!)
    }

}
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you testing your code on the emulator

Comment: Tested on both real device and emulator @ShubhamJain

Comment: and have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
as well in your Menifest

Comment: Yes, the app works well in online. This error just kicked in when I tried it without the internet connection

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257271/4853552

Comment: I have done that before too.. but when I remove the code to check the connection and just execute the network call , this error kept kicking in. I have edited the post Mr @ShubhamJain

Comment: Looks this line is culprit at com.network.datasource.CourseDetailsDataSourcecImpl.getChaptersByPagination(CourseDetailsDataSourcecImpl.kt:39) Show code for this class

Comment: Share CourseDetailsRepositoryImpl.kt

Comment: Ok I'll add it in the post @VVB

Comment: Do you find an answer?

Comment: Yes, @MahdiMoqadasi. I was using onErrorReturn method as I was using flatmap to call multiple network calls in chains. The side effect of this was onErrorReturn doesn't consume the exception thrown by the network call due to some kind of failure so it throws the exception so the app is inevitably crashed. That's why I used onErrorResumeNext instead. Then the crash is gone as it swallows the exception and the thrown exception can be handled on our own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using onErrorReturn method as I was using flatmap to call multiple network calls in chains. The side effect of this was onErrorReturn doesn't consume the exception thrown by the network call due to some kind of failure so it throws the exception so the app is inevitably crashed. That's why I used onErrorResumeNext instead. Then the crash is gone as it swallows the exception and the thrown exception can be handled on our own.